# WPF MultiBinding with and condition & nested or conditions

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I code this pseudo c# code in xaml:

```
if (button.Content =="Select" && (checkBox1.IsChecked || checkBox2.IsChecked))
```

I have tried Style.Triggers with DataTrigger and MultiDataTrigger with Condition, but none is giving me the combination I need.

Comment: As suggested you should update your question and include the relevant XAML and viewmodel code that you currently have - or better yet create a small [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that represents your problem. I'd suggest that no matter what, do not check your button content for a specific string - you must have a better option available than that?

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer given DRapp, it makes the most sense to just have a simple property to check the conditions, however here is what I think you we're trying to achieve with your `XAML`. As long as you set up those element names to match yours correctly and use the setter to apply your condition this should work.

```
<Style.Triggers>
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=button1, Path=Content}" Value="Select" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=checkBox1, Path=IsChecked }" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="SomeProperty" Value="SomeValue" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=button1, Path=Content}" Value="Select" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=checkBox2, Path=IsChecked }" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="SomeProperty" Value="SomeValue" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what you are trying to do in the WPF window/control, a little harder to answer.  However, in your binding context (MVVM, view model, control object), why not create a new property that returns Boolean and tests for both

```
public bool YourSpecialFlag
{ get { return button.Content == "Select" && ( checkBox1.IsChecked || checkBox2.IsChecked ); }}
```

If you can provide more of your form and model that you are binding to might offer more suggestions.  Also, if your checkboxes are have data binding to your control (whatever it is), then you would refer to that class properties directly.  Also implementing INotifyPropertyChanged can help turn on/off fields as you might be looking for.  I and others can provide more based on more from you.

Please EDIT your ORIGINAL POST providing more of the controlling object and also some sample XAML to see the bigger picture.